# linkbutton oncommand, onClick, RowCommand in grid view not firing

Tags: asp.net, gridview, command

I've read tens of posts about this issue and tried them all but with no luck, I'm not sure what am I missing this is gridview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="recentJobsGridView" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333"
                            GridLines="None" Height="151px" Width="541px" Visible="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                            PageSize="5" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="recentJobsGridView_PageIndexChanging"
                            DataKeyNames="orderItemId">
                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Order Date" Visible="true">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("orderItemId") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Order Date">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("orderDate") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="QTY">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("QTY") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Length">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("length") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="wall">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("wall") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Paper Composition">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("paperComposition") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="btAdd" runat="server" OnCommand="btAdd_Command"  Text="Add" 
                                        CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItem %>' CommandName="Add"></asp:LinkButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                        </asp:GridView>
```

here is where I bind the grid view:

```
 protected void custGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (custGridView.SelectedDataKey != null)
        {
            selectCustomer = (int)custGridView.SelectedDataKey.Value;
            recentJobsGridView.Visible = true;
            recentJobsGridView.DataSource = ViewDataSource(selectCustomer);
            recentJobsGridView.DataBind();
        }

    }
```

and this is the code of the LinkButton:

```
 protected void btAdd_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Add")
        {
            StatusLbl.Text = "Hellooooooo";
        }
    }
```

I removed everything I just want this message to be displayed but NOTHING is responding
Help please...

Comment: If you dont have the `!Ispostback` at the page load, the event from the gridview does not fire.

Comment: Thanks but I have it already at the page_load

Comment: I had this issue. I was binding the data for the grid in the Page_PreRender, needed to do so in the page_load.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see you are missing the `onrowcommand` in your gridview. Try this

```
asp:GridView ID="recentJobsGridView" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333"
                            GridLines="None" Height="151px" Width="541px" Visible="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                            PageSize="5" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="recentJobsGridView_PageIndexChanging"
                            DataKeyNames="orderItemId"  onrowcommand="recentJobsGridView_RowCommand">
```

then add this to your codeFile

```
 protected void recentJobsGridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName.Equals("Add")) 
            {
              StatusLbl.Text = "Hellooooooo";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the GridView's RowCommand event, which should fire on clicking the link button, with the command name/arg.

Comment: I think the problem is with binding the grid view when selecting a record from another gridview...what is the solution in this case??

Answer (score 0):

Remove `OnCommand="btAdd_Command"`, so `LinkButton` will be...

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" 
                CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItem %>' 
                CommandName="Add">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

And add `OnRowCommand="btAdd_Command"` inside `GridView`.

```
<asp:GridView ID="recentJobsGridView" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
              ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="151px" Width="541px" 
              Visible="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              PageSize="5" AllowPaging="True" 
              OnPageIndexChanging="recentJobsGridView_PageIndexChanging"
              DataKeyNames="orderItemId"
              OnRowCommand="btAdd_Command">
```

Now on Code Behind, modify the Button's definition like below...

```
protected void btAdd_Command(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // If multiple buttons are used in a GridView control, use the
    // CommandName property to determine which button was clicked.
    if (e.CommandName == "Add")
    {
        StatusLbl.Text = "Hellooooooo";
    }
}
```

Mark that you have to use `GridViewCommandEventArgs`, not `CommandEventArgs`.